# How to correct disappearing admin menu?

Tags: 7, routes, caching

I use the [Admin Menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module for my projects. In my Drupal 7 and Pressflow 7 instances, it randomly shows only some menu items.

At first, I thought I could correct this by clearing menu cache. When I went to the front page, I once again got the corrupted menu.

[image: wrong]

[image: correct]

How do I solve this error, permanently?

I found out [this issue is reported in detail](http://drupal.org/node/442560), but there is only a [workaround](http://drupal.org/node/442560#comment-2692220) (disable menu caching).

I disabled menu caching with `drush vset admin_menu_cache_client 0` as a workaround.
(I am still testing this issue with the menu cache enabled.)

I checked and eliminated JavaScript errors using Firebug browser extension.

I removed BOM from *.js files as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858757/945548).

Comment: [This](http://drupal.org/node/442560#comment-5517478) workaround is simplier to apply if you have Drush. It's the same as the above, just easier. Did you check for [BOM corrupted modules](http://drupal.org/node/442560#comment-5809644) on your intallation ?

Comment: I did in linux bash:

find . | xargs grep -l $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' > /tmp/bom.txt

and I found that a number of files *.js *.png *.jpg *.gif in /sites/all/libraries contain BOM characters. Should I also correct image files?

Comment: I don't think so, but the `js` files may definitely need attention.

Comment: Are you sure its not just an authorization/role settings problem?

Comment: I don't think so, I use uid 1 and I still get this error.

Comment: @Countzero, I removed BOM from all js files but the error still exists.

Comment: Well, I can hardly help further then. Just to be sure, did you check the rights in the `files`folders and children ? Sometimes buggy javascript comes from inability to write in some of these folders. But it's just guessing.

Answer (score 4):

*Modules* > *Administration Menu* > *Configure*

In the Performance tab, untick **Cache menu in client-side browser**.

Save configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to the bottom of your settings.php file:

`$conf['admin_menu_cache_client'] = FALSE;`

Comment: `Cache menu in client-side browser` in Modules > Administration Menu > Configure doesn't worked for me, but this one does.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for rebuilding, although it refreshes all the menus.
If the user has the permission to access that menu, it will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with this, but it had to do with the mod_rewrite module in Apache's config file (httpd.conf). Make sure it's not commented out!

This:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Instead of this:

```
# LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

As soon as I did that, my admin menu appeared again and it fixed another issue with my configuration changes not saving.

Answer (score 0):

In your profile settings: uncheck the "Use the overlay for administrative pages." option under "Administrative overlay".